# Storing and Instantiating a Scala class in a container/variable

Tags: scala, types

I need to return a class based on the key string, and then instantiate the returned type. 
For example:

```
class A 
class B

val keyType = Map[String, Any ???] ("a" -> A, "b" -> B) ??? does not work
val t = keyType("a") ???
val i = ??? instantiate type A
```

However, `"a" -> A` does not work, furthermore, I'm not sure how to instantiate the class stored in a variable  `t`.

What could be the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, [`classOf`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.2/index.html#scala.Predef$@classOf[T]:Class[T]) is available inside of [`Predef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.2/index.html#scala.Predef$), so to make a `Map[String, Class]` you simply need to call it, parameterized with the type you need to access:

```
val keyType: Map[String, Class[_]] = Map("a" -> classOf[A], "b" -> classOf[B])
val t = keyType("a")
// t is a Class[_ >: B with A <: Object]
```

Second, all classes have a [`newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) method (courtesy of inheriting from `java.lang.Class`), so you can just call that method:

```
val i = t.newInstance
// This assumes that you don't need to provide any arguments
```

Comment: What to do if I need to give parameters?

Comment: @Sean Just out of curiosity, I had an answer which was similar to yours, the difference is that I was matching on the `keyType("a")` result since you don't now a priori the type of the result, and in fact this: `val t: Class[A] = keyType("a")` doesn't compile for me since the compiler expects a `Class[_]`, am I missing something?

Comment: @EndeNeu - true - apologies, I have a habit of sketching the result - removing the assertion (since it really is a `Class[_ >: B with A <: Object]`) makes it compile.

Comment: @prosseek - use [`getConstructor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) (also from `java.lang.Class`) or use something [like this](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/dynamically-creating-instances-tp1953575p1953585.html)